# python how to convert amount of seconds passed from day to a date and time value?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas time series containing the number of seconds since 1rst January 1970. How can I get the actual date ?

My data is:

```
In [119]: train_flows.Last.head()
Out[119]: 

0    1473894892
1    1473894892
2    1473894891
3    1473894891
4    1473894899
Name: Last, dtype: int64
```

An I would like to transform `1473894892` in something like `10.00.00 of the 20th October 2015`.

Comment: try this: `train_flows.Last = pd.to_datetime(train_flows.Last, unit='s')`

Comment: it works!. Thanks a lot